# Adding items to NSMutableArray not working

Tags: iphone, ios, nsmutablearray

I am trying to create an array of numbers that I will use later to determin the size of my tableviewcells.

However I am having some issues with the array, After my while statment it comes back as being NULL, yet when I log the values I am getting from my array of objects they are correct... and the if statement works perfectly.

This is my code

```
int count = 0;

// Cell heights
int smallCell = 69;
int largeCell = 120;

NSNumber *currentHeight = [[NSNumber alloc] init]; // allows int to be stored into NSArray

while (count < seriesSearchArray.count) {
    myObj = (SeriesSearchResultItem*)[dataArrayOfObjects objectAtIndex:count];

    if (![myObj.seriesNote isEqualToString:@""]) {
        NSLog(@"%@", myObj.seriesNote);
        currentHeight = [NSNumber numberWithInt:largeCell];
        NSLog(@"%@", currentHeight); // correct value shown
        [heightArray addObject:currentHeight];
    }
    else {
        currentHeight = [NSNumber numberWithInt:smallCell];
        NSLog(@"%@", currentHeight); // correct value shown
        [heightArray addObject:currentHeight];
    }


    NSLog(@"%@", heightArray); // NULL Shown

    count ++;
}
```

So thats if, I am trying to get the value from each of the objects in my array which works, the if statment works perfectly but then when I try to add them to my new array it always comes back as NULL.

Comment: You may need to show more code.  I don't see you create (alloc/init) the heightArray.  Then again, that could be the problem...

Comment: I have @property/@synthesized heightArray, because I need to access it from another method after I have put the values into it.

Comment: That creates the pointer to it.  It doesn't actually create the NSMutableArray.  You need something like heightArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:seriesSearchArray.count]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving comment to answer

You need something like

```
heightArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:seriesSearchArray.count]
```

Comment: Similar approaches would be to do `[[NSMutableArray alloc] init]`, `[@[] mutableCopy]`, or to lazily instantiate it by doing any of these options in the getter for the array if it is nil.